# Alternative axioms for inner product on real vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> The axioms that define an inner product in a vector space $V$ are
>
> 1. **Positivity** $\langle v,v\rangle\ge 0$ for all $v\in V$
> 2. **Definiteness** $\langle v,v\rangle=0\iff v=0$
> 3. **Additivity in first slot** $\langle u+v,w\rangle=\langle u,w\rangle+\langle v,w\rangle$ for all $u,v,w\in V$
> 4. **Homogeneity in first slot** $\langle\lambda u,v\rangle=\lambda\langle u,v\rangle$ for all $\lambda\in\Bbb F$
> 5. **Conjugate symmetry** $\langle u,v\rangle=\overline{\langle v,u\rangle}$ for all $u,v\in V$

Now the exercise ask

> Prove that for a non-zero real vector space if we change the first axiom (positivity) by
>
> 1. Exists some $v\in V$ such that $\langle v,v\rangle>0$
>
> then the set of functions that define an inner product on $V$ is the same.

Im completely stuck in this exercise. I tried to prove it by contradiction: WLOG suppose that exists two linearly independent $x,y\in V$ with $\langle x,x\rangle >0$ and $\langle y,y\rangle<0$ such that

$$\langle x,x\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle=0$$

But from here Im unable to show a contradiction. Some help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: https://todayiproved.blogspot.com/2017/08/in-real-vector-space-slightly-weaker.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have linearly independent vectors $x$ and $y$ with $\langle x,x\rangle>0>\langle y,y\rangle$, consider $\langle z,z\rangle$ for $z$ on the line segment joining $x$ to $y$.

Comment: For $z=tx+(1-t)y$, the inner product $\langle z,z\rangle$ is a quadratic function of $t$, and it should be possible to explicitly find the value of $t$ that makes it vanish.

Comment: oh, ok... I think I get it... thank you!